# dnsmasq gives a correct response then a connection time out

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq, nslookup

When trying to nslookup to my dnsmasq dns server I get the correct IP address and then I get a `connection timed out : no servers could be reached` message. Any idea what is happening here and if I can still use it or better find out what is wrong?

```
[diis@master1 preparation]$ nslookup node1
Server:         192.168.0.10
Address:        192.168.0.10#53

Name:   node1.example.com
Address: 192.168.0.20
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Moreover, it's interesting that dig does not run into a timeout.

Comment: The timeout is occurring after the first response because `nslookup` makes 2 queries (A for IPv4 and AAAA for IPv6) - the initial A query has succeeded and a response has been received, but the AAAA query has timed out because an IPv6 address is not received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it on my server.

Try adding the following to your dnsmasq config:

```
local=/node1/
```

It tells dnsmasq to resolve those domain names only locally using `/etc/hosts`.